# Unique Record Insertion Best Practice in SQL Server CE Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce

Should the database engine do all the work, or should the responsibility of checking for uniqueness be the responsibility of the client application?

I’m developing an application in C# to scan drives and store file information in a SQL Server CE database and I would like to know which way of ensuring unique entries is "best". So far I tried the following three approaches and haven’t seen any difference in performance:

1. Maintaining a collection object
2. Checking for existence in the database
3. Relying on a unique index in the database

Pseudo code of my three approaches. The actual code breaks the file up into its parts and uses several tables to store path, extension, volume/server, and other information,  plus indexing records to look up data.

```
collectionObj //initialize with existing records from database
While (filesToAdd.Count > 0 )
{
    file = filesToAdd.Dequeue();
    If(!collectionObj.Contains( file.Name ))
    {
        Insert file.Name into database
        collectionObj.Add(file.Name)
      }
}
```

With method 1 I thought it would be faster to search an object in memory, but since a SQL Server CE database is also in memory I’m not so sure of the benefit.

```
While (filesToAdd.Count > 0 )
{
    file = filesToAdd.Dequeue();

    if(  ( select count(*) from database where filename = file.Name) == 0 )  
    {
       Insert file.Name into database
    }
}
```

Method 2 doesn’t use any extra objects/memory but queries the database a lot looking for duplicates. With SQL Server CE network traffic isn’t a problem but excessive querying has to have an effect on performance.

```
While (filesToAdd.Count > 0 )
{
        file = filesToAdd.Dequeue();
        try
       {
          Insert file.Name into database
       }catch(Duplicate index violation exception)
       {
          //do nothing 
       }
}
```

I’m leaning towards method 3 mainly because it simplifies the code, but it seems to lazy to be a best practice. Also on duplicate insertions the database is throwing an error and so is the program. That seems like it would impact performance.

Given the information provided, which is the "best" way for adding a lot of information into a database when you know there will be many duplicates? Does the answer change if the data is primarily unique or mainly duplicates? If you have an even better approach then what I have thought of I would be happy to hear it. My question is specifically about SQL Server CE which doesn’t have the full power of SQL Server, please keep that in mind when offering suggestions.

Comment: It looks like everyone unanimously agrees that setting a unique constraint on the table is the best way to prevent duplicate values in the database.  Additionally, there may not even be much benefit to trying to filter the values before attempting the insert/update.   Gordon Linoff very good in-depth answer, but I selected Gary Walker because his answer is the most practical.  I guess the question I have now is if I were going to filter values before inserting should I use Method 1 or 2 (more code and memory usage vs. database overhead)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is as usual, it depends. The "lazy" solution of having the database do it is ultimately the correct answer. However, if you can filter out duplicates on the client, and the time and effort to filter out  has enough benefit to keep from having the database perform all of the filtering, then filtering on the client makes sense. You will still enforce uniqueness on the database, but you might be able to offload some of its  processing by filtering out some or most duplicates on the client. I would probably only go this route if I know from actual application experience that it would be worth the effort.

Comment: A combination approach, I like that ideal.  It makes sense to use Method1 to maintain small collections of values where you expect many duplicates.  For example in my program I could use the collectionObj to filter out extension types, but let unique constraints on the tables handle inserting file names and directories. I moved from Method1 to Method2 because my collection objects started to take up a lot of memory as I was indexing 100,000's of files in almost 20,000 directories. However, I didn’t know if searching a collection or the database was more efficient since are both in memory.

Comment: I thought you mentioned filtering on the client. If so, the filtering should essentially be free (in terms of database overhead). You can have a web-server (or whatever mid-tier server) cache the data sent to the client that relates to the bulk of the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is . . . do it in the database.

The uniqueness requirement is a requirement of the *data*.  The database should be used to enforce these requirements.

Remember that ensuring unique entries requiring doing tests for both `insert` and `update`.  And, you want the uniqueness as part of your data integrity.  So, you want the check to happen regardless of how the update or insert is being done (through your application, manually, via a trigger, or whatever).  The only way to guarantee that it is always done is to do the check in the database.

This argument transcends performance.  However, the database should be quite efficient with a performance check, assuming the unique index fits into memory.  There might be some situations where performance is so paramount that constraints would be checked in the application.  These would be few and far between.  And, I might question why a database is being used for the data store for such an application.

Comment: In designing my application I hadn’t considered updates, that’s a good argument for relying on the constraint.  Checking for uniqueness before every change to the data is a lot more code. Updates and inserts occurring outside the program is more of a concern for SQL Server but your point is still valid.  In this program I value data integrity more than performance, although speed is still important.

Answer (score 0):

Why would a lazy good method be a bad method?

If you are going to use a database to store data and you want to be sure there are no duplicate entries, then of course should enfore the UNIQUE constraint to your rows. Not only does it help you maintain a duplicate-free data storage, but it will also provide you with a good way of identifying each row.

If there is a duplicate entry, the database engine will notice this while inserting to the database and throw an error/exception that you easily can catch.

Comment: I completely agree with your opinion.   It’s less code, no collection objects in memory, and will prevent all duplicates.  However, I’m worried about performance with the database throwing a lot of errors.  Say I’m trying to insert 1000 records and 990 are duplicates.  Generating all those exceptions seems inefficient.  If I know many will be duplicates shouldn’t I try to filter them out before sending the command to the DB?  Maybe since the SQLCE database is loaded into memory with the program, the performance hit won’t be as noticeable as in an application talking to a networked SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you want your database to handle the unique constraints but it sounds like you're wanting to avoid the exceptions that get thrown when attempting to insert a duplicate record. Normally, I would suggest using IF NOT EXISTS in your SQL INSERT statement but you can't do that with SQL Server Compact.

Another trick might be to try an UPDATE first and if no rows are affected, you know the record doesn't exist and you can safely INSERT it. It's a little bit of extra work but if you're expecting a lot of duplicates, it might still be more efficient than catching all those exceptions.

It might also be wise to try to filter out known duplicates before even trying to put them into the database. Perhaps consider using a HashSet to keep track of the unique IDs that you've already inserted during that session. If a value is in your HashSet, you know you can just skip it and save yourself a call to the database.

Comment: You’re right I don’t like the ideal of knowingly causing exceptions.   When I realized IF NOT EXISTS wouldn’t work I used Method1 of maintaining a collection of values in the program to do the filtering.  My collectionObj is a HashTable where key = item and value = SELECT @@IDENTITY after the insert. If I just stored the values for the session I would still get duplicates for all the values already in the database.

You suggested testing UPDATE to check for existing values, and in Method2 I use SELECT to check for existence.  Is UPDATE more efficient at this type of task than SELECT?

Comment: I mentioned UPDATE mostly because I've had a few situations lately that were similar where I needed to update the existing record so the pattern was fresh in my head. But reading is always faster than both reading and writing so if you don't need to UPDATE, a SELECT would be better.